# My dicord bot doesn't respond to commands

Tags: python, discord

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=discord.Intents.default())
TOKEN = "TOKEN"


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Bot connected as {bot.user}')


@bot.command()
async def dosomething(ctx):
    await ctx.send("I did something")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Bot is active and everything but when I try out /dosomething command nothing happens.

Answer (score -1):

`Change The Prefix` To Anything Else But Not "/"

And Try `Intents.all()`

As i Know , Using `/commands` Needs Other libraries

Like This : [discord_slash](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/)

Comment: Slash commands are usable in d.py 2.0. Other libraries are no longer required.